# How to know which page has called the Usercontrol

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a usercontrol(.ascx) page that is used by about 10 pages to display something in common. In the control i should know which aspx page is using(or calling). How is that possible?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check `Request.Url` or `(Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler`.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the page object by calling:

```
this.Page
```

Or the URL by calling

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url
```

Answer (score 2):

The control has a [`Page`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.page.aspx) property that will be set to the page that it is on.